# Unpacking arguments: only named arguments may follow *expression

Tags: python, arrays, arguments

The following works beautifully in Python:

```
def f(x,y,z): return [x,y,z]

a=[1,2]

f(3,*a)
```

The elements of `a` get unpacked as if you had called it like `f(3,1,2)` and it returns `[3,1,2]`. Wonderful!

But I can't unpack the elements of `a` into the *first* two arguments:

```
f(*a,3)
```

Instead of calling that like `f(1,2,3)`, I get "SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression".

I'm just wondering why it has to be that way and if there's any clever trick I might not be aware of for unpacking arrays into arbitrary parts of argument lists without resorting to temporary variables.

Comment: `f(*a, 3)` now works in Python 3.5

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As Raymond Hettinger's answer points out, this <s>may change</s> has changed in Python 3 and [here is a related proposal](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), which has been accepted.
Especially related to the current question, here's one of the possible changes to that proposal that was discussed:

> Only allow a starred expression as the last item in the exprlist. This would simplify the 
>   unpacking code a bit and allow for the starred expression to be assigned an iterator. This 
>   behavior was rejected because it would be too surprising.

So there are implementation reasons for the restriction with unpacking function arguments but it is indeed a little surprising!

In the meantime, here's the workaround I was looking for, kind of obvious in retrospect:

```
f(*(a+[3]))
```

Comment: And if `a` is tuple: `f(*(a+(3,)))`

Comment: The brackets are not needed. Thus for lists `f(*a+[3])` and for tuples `f(*a+(3,))`

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't *have to* be that way.  It was just rule that Guido found to be sensible.

In Python 3, the rules for unpacking have been liberalized somewhat:

```
>>> a, *b, c = range(10)
>>> a
0
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> c
9
```

Depending on whether Guido feels it would improve the language, that liberalization could also be extended to function arguments.

See the discussion on [extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for some thoughts on why Python 3 changed the rules.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! I didn't mean to phrase it as "have to" but was curious about the rationale. Sounds like it may have been rather arbitrary. As for a workaround, looks like `apply(f, a+[3])` would do it, though I see that apply() is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks again for the elucidating answer. See also my answer for more about this, and the workaround I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to the [PEP 448 - Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/),

```
f(*a, 3)
```

is [now accepted syntax starting from Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations). Likewise you can use the double-star `**` for keyword argument unpacking anywhere and either one can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

`f` is expecting 3 arguments (`x`, `y`, `z`, in that order).

Suppose `L = [1,2]`. When you call `f(3, *L)`, what python does behind the scenes, is to call `f(3, 1, 2)`, without really knowing the length of `L`.

So what happens if `L` was instead `[1,2,3]`?

Then, when  you call `f(3, *L)`, you'll end up calling `f(3,1,2,3)`, which will be an error because `f` is expecting exactly 3 arguments and you gave it 4.

Now, suppose `L=[1,2]1. Look at what happens when you call`f`:

```
>>> f(3,*L) # works fine
>>> f(*L) # will give you an error when f(1,2) is called; insufficient arguments
```

Now, you implicitly know when you call `f(*L, 3)` that 3 will be assigned to `z`, but python doesn't know that. It only knows that the last `j` many elements of the input to `f` will be defined by the contents of `L`. But since it doesn't know the value of `len(L)`, it can't make assumptions about whether `f(*L,3)` would have the correct number of arguments.

This however, is not the case with `f(3,*L)`. In this case, python knows that all the arguments EXCEPT the first one will be defined by the contents of `L`.

But if you have named arguments `f(x=1, y=2, z=3)`, then the arguments being assigned to by name will be bound first. Only then are the positional arguments bound. So you do `f(*L, z=3)`. In that case, `z` is bound to `3` first, and then, the other values get bound.

Now interestingly, if you did `f(*L, y=3)`, that would give you an error for trying to assign to `y` twice (once with the keyword, once again with the positional)

Hope this helps

Comment: I think I may disagree with this, in particular the "python doesn't know that" part. As Raymond Hettinger says, it seems to be an arbitrary restriction. I could imagine an efficiency argument against the liberalization though.

Comment: Possible. I've shared this question on G+, tagged to Guido. Let's see if he says something

Answer (score 3):

You can use `f(*a, z=3)` if you use `f(*a, 3)`, it do not know how to unpack the parameter for you provided 2 parameters and 2 is the second.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted, it's a very good answer for python 2. More readable than the *(a+(b,)) trick

Answer (score 2):

Nice. This also works for tuples. Don't forget the comma:

```
a = (1,2)
f(*(a+(3,)))
```