# Generator as function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, python-2.x, generator-expression

Can anyone explain why passing a generator as the only positional argument to a function seems to have special rules?

If we have:

```
def f(*args):
    print "Success!"
    print args
```

1. This works, as expected.

   ```
   >>> f(1, *[2])
   Success!
   (1, 2)
   ```
2. This does not work, as expected.

   ```
   >>> f(*[2], 1)
     File "<stdin>", line 1
   SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
   ```
3. This works, as expected

   ```
   >>> f(1 for x in [1], *[2])
   Success! 
   (generator object <genexpr> at 0x7effe06bdcd0>, 2)
   ```
4. This works, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't it fail in the same way as 2)

   ```
   >>> f(*[2], 1 for x in [1])
   Success!
   (generator object <genexpr> at 0x7effe06bdcd0>, 2)
   ```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720450/unpacking-arguments-only-named-arguments-may-follow-expression. TL;DR seems like it's an implementation detail - it just works like that.

Comment: Note: case 2 should work in python 3.5+ (due to the [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/))

Comment: Python 3.5 is out, and it now tells that the case 3 (actually also the case 4) has been fixed. [What's new in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.5.html#changes-in-python-behavior)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Both 3. and 4. *should* be syntax errors on all Python versions.** However you've found a bug that affects Python versions 2.5 - 3.4, and which was subsequently [posted to the Python issue tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue25070). Because of the bug, an unparenthesized generator expression was accepted as an argument to a function if it was accompanied only by `*args` and/or `**kwargs`. While Python 2.6+ allowed both cases 3. and 4., Python 2.5 allowed only case 3. - yet both of them were against the [documented grammar](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/calls.html):

```
call    ::=     primary "(" [argument_list [","]
                            | expression genexpr_for] ")"
```

i.e. the documentation says a function call comprises of `primary` (the expression that evaluates to a callable), followed by, in parentheses, *either* an argument list *or* just an unparenthesized generator expression;
and within the argument list, all generator expressions must be in parentheses.

---

This bug (though it seems it had not been known), had been fixed in Python 3.5 prereleases. In Python 3.5 parentheses are always required around a generator expression, unless it is the only argument to the function:

```
Python 3.5.0a4+ (default:a3f2b171b765, May 19 2015, 16:14:41) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f(1 for i in [42], *a)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

This is now documented in the [What's New in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.5.html#changes-in-python-behavior), thanks to DeTeReR spotting this bug.

---

### Analysis of the bug

There was a change made to Python 2.6 which [allowed the use of keyword arguments *after* `*args`](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#other-language-changes):

> It’s also become legal to provide keyword arguments after a *args
>   argument to a function call.
>
> ```
> >>> def f(*args, **kw):
> ...     print args, kw
> ...
> >>> f(1,2,3, *(4,5,6), keyword=13)
> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) {'keyword': 13}
> ```
>
> Previously this would have been a syntax error. (Contributed by Amaury
>   Forgeot d’Arc; issue 3473.)

---

However, the Python 2.6 [grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.6/Grammar/Grammar#L133) does not make any distinction between keyword arguments, positional arguments, or bare generator expressions - they are all of type `argument` to the parser.

As per Python rules, a generator expression must be parenthesized if it is not the sole argument to the function. This is validated in the [`Python/ast.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.6/Python/ast.c#L1906):

```
for (i = 0; i < NCH(n); i++) {
    node *ch = CHILD(n, i);
    if (TYPE(ch) == argument) {
        if (NCH(ch) == 1)
            nargs++;
        else if (TYPE(CHILD(ch, 1)) == gen_for)
            ngens++;
        else
            nkeywords++;
    }
}
if (ngens > 1 || (ngens && (nargs || nkeywords))) {
    ast_error(n, "Generator expression must be parenthesized "
              "if not sole argument");
    return NULL;
}
```

However this function does *not* consider the `*args` at all - it specifically only looks for ordinary positional arguments and keyword arguments.

Further down in the same function, there is an error message generated for [non-keyword arg after keyword arg](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.6/Python/ast.c#L1931):

```
if (TYPE(ch) == argument) {
    expr_ty e;
    if (NCH(ch) == 1) {
        if (nkeywords) {
            ast_error(CHILD(ch, 0),
                      "non-keyword arg after keyword arg");
            return NULL;
        }
        ...
```

But this again applies to arguments that are *not* unparenthesized generator expressions as [evidenced by the `else if` statement](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.6/Python/ast.c#L1945):

```
else if (TYPE(CHILD(ch, 1)) == gen_for) {
    e = ast_for_genexp(c, ch);
    if (!e)
        return NULL;
    asdl_seq_SET(args, nargs++, e);
}
```

Thus an unparenthesized generator expression was allowed to slip pass.

---

Now in Python 3.5 one can use the `*args` anywhere in a function call, so
the [Grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Grammar/Grammar#L126) was changed to accommodate for this:

```
arglist: argument (',' argument)*  [',']
```

and

```
argument: ( test [comp_for] |
            test '=' test |
            '**' test |
            '*' test )
```

and the [`for` loop was changed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Python/ast.c#L2628) to

```
for (i = 0; i < NCH(n); i++) {
    node *ch = CHILD(n, i);
    if (TYPE(ch) == argument) {
        if (NCH(ch) == 1)
            nargs++;
        else if (TYPE(CHILD(ch, 1)) == comp_for)
            ngens++;
        else if (TYPE(CHILD(ch, 0)) == STAR)
            nargs++;
        else
            /* TYPE(CHILD(ch, 0)) == DOUBLESTAR or keyword argument */
            nkeywords++;
    }
}
```

Thus fixing the bug.

However the inadvertent change is that the valid looking constructions

```
func(i for i in [42], *args)
```

and

```
func(i for i in [42], **kwargs)
```

where an unparenthesized generator precedes `*args` or `**kwargs` now stopped working.

---

To locate this bug, I tried various Python versions. In 2.5 you'd get `SyntaxError`:

```
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Nov 28 2010, 16:43:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f(*[1], 2 for x in [2])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f(*[1], 2 for x in [2])
```

And this was fixed before some prerelease of Python 3.5:

```
Python 3.5.0a4+ (default:a3f2b171b765, May 19 2015, 16:14:41) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f(*[1], 2 for x in [2])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

However, the parenthesized generator expression, it works in Python 3.5, but it does not work not in Python 3.4:

```
f(*[1], (2 for x in [2]))
```

And this is the clue. In Python 3.5 the `*splatting` is generalized; you can use it anywhere in a function call:

```
>>> print(*range(5), 42)
0 1 2 3 4 42
```

So the actual bug (generator working with `*star` without parentheses) *was* indeed fixed in Python 3.5, and the bug could be found in that what changed between Python 3.4 and 3.5

Comment: It's not fixed in 3.5 - just put parens around the generator and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @viraptor good point, in 3.4 the *parenthesized* expression gives an error

Comment: huh? Running on 3.4.3: `f(*[1], 1 for x in [1])` => `(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fa56c889288>, 1)`

Comment: @viraptor `f(*[1], (1 for x in [1]))` is syntax error on Python 3.4. It is valid in Python 3.5.

Comment: I would gild this answer if I could, thanks for including the relevant C source!