# Difference between max([a for a in [1,2]]) and max(a for a in [1,2]) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found both of them will output the expected result `2`.

- `max([a for a in [1,2]])` is `max()` + `list comprehension`, an easy one.
- `max(a for a in [1,2])` is `max()` + `?`. Why does it work? What do we name the structure `a for a in [1,2]`?

A generator is in form of `(a for a in [1,2])`. I doubt that the `(a for a in [1,2])` insides `max(a for a in [1,2])` is a generator. However, if that's the case, why can a pair of `()` be ignored? Technically speaking it should be `max((a for a in [1,2]))`.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually easy to find out what it is if you replace `max` with `print`.

Comment: What is your python version? This seems to be a bug fixed since then: https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.5.html#changes-in-python-behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generator as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521140/generator-as-function-argument)

Comment: @nocibambi it's not a bug if it's a single argument.

Comment: @nocibambi The bug was allowing multi-argument calls to not have their own pair: "Python 3.5 now correctly raises a SyntaxError, as generator expressions must be put in parentheses if not a sole argument to a function."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is in fact a generator expression. Generator expressions can make use of the `()` from argument lists; providing that they're the only argument passed to the function. If there are more arguments, they require their own pair of parenthesis.

You can verify this yourself with a quick test:

```
def func(arg):
    print(type(arg))

func(n for n in range(10))  # Prints <class 'generator'>
```

---

From [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#the-details):

> The syntax requires that a generator expression always needs to be directly inside a set of parentheses and cannot have a comma on either side. . . .  [I]f a function call has a single positional argument, it can be a generator expression without extra parentheses, but in all other cases you have to parenthesize it.