# swap axes in 3d wirefram plot (matplotlib) due to SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-3.4, argument-unpacking

I'm on Python 3.4.3 and cannot upgrade the system.
My issue is that I want do generate 3d wireframe plot using `matplotlib` and `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d`

```
ax.plot_wireframe(*a,b, rstride=1, cstride=2)
>> SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720450/unpacking-arguments-only-named-arguments-may-follow-expression) I get, that prior Python 3.5 a starred expression is only allowed as the last item in the exprlist.

Doing `ax.plot_wireframe(b,*a, rstride=1, cstride=2)` works, but this - of course - yields in a plot with twisted-up axes.

My question:
Is there a possibilty to swap the axis from the wirefram plot (e.q. `ax.plot_wireframe(Z,X,Y)` instead `(X,Y,Z)`, or is there another workaround for my problem with the unpacking?

Further details:

```
a = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ys.shape[0]),xs)
b = ys.T

print(ys.shape)
>>(448, 33)
print(ys.shape[0])
>>488
print(b.shape)
>>(33,448)
print(xs.shape)
>>(33,)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I was able to circumvent the problem by giving Python what it wanted, namely a named argument.
So the line now reads:

```
ax.plot_wireframe(*a,Z=b)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about *chain* `b` to `a` using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and unpack both of them in one piece:

```
from itertools import chain

ax.plot_wireframe(*chain(a, (b,)), rstride=1, cstride=2)
```

If `a` is a list or tuple, you can of course simply use addition after putting `b` in a container of *type* `a`.

---

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = 4
>>> print(*a, b)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
>>> print(b, *a)
4 1 2 3
>>> print(*chain(a, (b,)))
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: ax.plot_wireframe(*chain(a, (b,))) yields File "~/Python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1775, in plot_wireframe
    linec = art3d.Line3DCollection(lines, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~/Python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 171, in __init__
    LineCollection.__init__(self, segments, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 12 positional arguments but 34 were given

Comment: @t.rathjen Have a look at the demo.

Comment: Be sure the case you have an error with works with `b, *a`

Comment: 'b, *a' works just fine, but than again, the axes don't match up