# mix * argument with regular argument

Tags: python

I have the following code to use * argument for a function.

```
inputs = [fill(input) for input in input_shapes]
# num_runs is an integer 
def bench(num_runs):
    inputs.append(num_runs) # can I remove this?
    handle_type(*inputs)
    del inputs[-1] # can I remove this?
```

I want to know a better way to handle `*inputs`, so I don't have to call `append` and `del` every time.

I tried a simple example:

```
inputs = [1, 2, 3]
inputs2 = [1, 2] 
def Test(a, b, c):
     print (a, b, c)


Test(*inputs) # works 
Test(*inputs2, 3) # SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

I found a solution here [Unpacking arguments: only named arguments may follow *expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720450/unpacking-arguments-only-named-arguments-may-follow-expression) and it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this, at least in reasonably recent Python 3 versions:

```py
inputs = [fill(input) for input in input_shapes]
def bench(num_runs):
    handle_type(*inputs, num_runs)
```